# Comparing value with previous row in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data={'col1':[1,3,3,1,2,3,2,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1'])
print df


     col1  
0     1          
1     3          
2     3          
3     1          
4     2          
5     3          
6     2          
7     2
```

I have the following Pandas DataFrame and I want to create another column that compares the previous row of col1 to see if the value of the row is greater than that of the previous row. It should come out like the following:

```
    col1  match  
0     1   False     
1     3   False     
2     3   True     
3     1   False     
4     2   False     
5     3   True     
6     2   False     
7     2   True
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare shifted values by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html),last missing value is replaced to `-1` for `True`, working, if all values are positive:

```
df['match'] = df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].shift(-1, fill_value=-1))
print (df)

   col1  match
0     1  False
1     3  False
2     3   True
3     1  False
4     2  False
5     3   True
6     2  False
7     2   True
```

If need last value set to `True` for any Dataframe:

```
df['match'] = df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].shift(-1))
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'match'] = True
```

Comment: Is it only work with `gt`? or the operator `>=` would work too?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Another quick question here: what if I want to compare row values with custom operations? Say print "True" if the value of a row is greater than that of the previous row by 20%?

Comment: @adirabargil - gt is like `>`, for `=>` is used `ge`

Comment: @NovaPoi - 20% Do you need 20% from values and compare? Not understand, I think it should be new question.

Comment: @NovaPoi - or need `df['match'] = df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].mul(0.2).shift(-1, fill_value=-1))` ?